# How to set default postgresql schema for laravel?

Tags: php, postgresql, laravel, laravel-5.4

I created new postgresql user:

```
CREATE ROLE lara_user SUPERUSER LOGIN PASSWORD 'mypassword';
```

Then create schema which is owned by this user

```
CREATE schema lara AUTHORIZATION lara_user;
```

In Laravel's `.env` file I have

```
DB_DATABASE=postgres
DB_USERNAME=lara_user
DB_PASSWORD=mypassword
```

Laravel don't sees schema `lara` and still connected to `public` schema.

How can I change and set default schema `lara` for Laravel ?

Comment: You can set the schema in `app/config/database.php`, using the `schema` array key in the appropriate connection. This can either be hard-coded, or reference a new `DB_SCHEMA` constant from `.env`

Comment: Added `DB_SCHEMA=lara` in `.env` file, though my Laravel application still successfully sees tables which I have in `public` schema (and don't have in `lara` schema)

Comment: @iainn - `DB_SCHEMA` in `.env` file not worked, though changing schema in `app/config/database.php` file works, thank you.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

in `app/config/database.php`

```
'pgsql' => array(
            'driver'   => 'pgsql',
            'host'     => 'localhost',
            'database' => 'forge',
            'username' => 'forge',
            'password' => '',
            'charset'  => 'utf8',
            'prefix'   => '',
            'schema'   => 'public',
        ),
```

in new version of laravel change

```
'schema'   => 'public',
```

to

```
'search_path' => 'public',
```

Comment: probably  do you mean needed schema name here: `'schema'   => 'public'`. I changed it to `lara` and it works, thank you

Comment: If someone is having issues conneting to *AWS RedShift* and doesn't know how to connect their own Database. The `schema` name should be set to their database name.

Comment: And for those with Lumen looking for where app/config/database.php is: add `DB_SCHEMA=lara` into your .env file

Comment: For current laravel version 'schema' is now called `search_path`.