# How to mention the postgres schema in laravel request file

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql, validation, laravel-5.5

I'm using Laravel 5.5 and I want to define a unique validation for a table column `column_x` located inside a Postgres schema `schema_x`, I've tried :

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'column_x' => 'required|unique:schema_x.table_x'
    ];
}
```

But the following error keeps raising :

> SQLSTATE[42P01]: Undefined table: 7 ERROR: relation "table_x" does not exist

I can't find any information about this case in the official documentation (**[Validation Section](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation)**).

Comment: If you have schema specified in database config you don't need to specify it again. See [tihs answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45242853/4471134)

Comment: I've more than 10 schemas, do I have to create a config for every schema? if so how to switch between them every time?

Comment: try this `'column_x' => 'required|unique:schema_x_connection.table_x,column_x'` here `schema_x_connection` is a connection that you have in `database.php` in `connections` array

Comment: check `Custom Database Connection` https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#rule-unique

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki Then you have to create 10 connections: a connection for each schema, rkj is right. See laracasts related: [1](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/controllervalidate-unique-specify-postgres-schema), [2](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/eloquent-postgresql-multi-schema-db-architecture)

Comment: Ok guys, thank you, I'm checking...