# Laravel 6 unique return Undefined table or Database [] not configured

Tags: laravel, postgresql, unique

Hi I added validation to form:

```
$rules = [
    'name' => 'required|max:255|unique:testcrm.permissions,name'
];
```

I using PostgreSQL. I have table `permissions` with column `unique` 'name'.
I have this same error which is in this [theme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51320804/how-to-mention-the-postgres-schema-in-laravel-request-file).

When I have:

```
unique:permissions,name'
```

Laravel return error:

> Undefined table:...

When I change to:

```
unique:testcrm.permissions,name
```

I have error:

> Database [testcrm] not configured.

I have:

**database name:** testid,

**schema name:** testcrm,

**table name:** permissions.

Comment: It's not about your database name, but the name of your connection in `database.php` Do you have a connection named: `testcrm`?

Comment: @Ruub I have config in `.env` and I have `DB_DATABASE=testid`. `testcrm` is name of schema

Answer (score 0):

```
'name' => 'required|unique:testcrm.permissions,name|max:255'
```

This validation should work.

In your .env file though you should have something like this:

`DB_CONNECTION=pgsql // define that you are using the pgsql connection`

Laravel connection is `Mysql` by default so make sure you change that

The rest are your credentials. After that run `php artisan config:cache` so your changes are being cached and loaded in the project.

Comment: Hi, I have in `.env` setting `DB_CONNECTION=pgsql`. But when I use your validation, still I have error Database [testcrm] not configured. P.S Connection to database work correctly.